# Access Javascript from Java

Tags: java, javascript

I m trying to access JavaScript function from Servlet code. But I'm getting the error shown below.
Here is the code:

```
out.println("<FRAME src=\"javascript:parent.newWindow('" + URL+ "') \" scrolling=No noresize />");
```

And this is the error that occurs in JavaScript:

> Object does not support this property or method;

Comment: Are you sure you try to access Javascript function from Servlet code? Maybe you try to GENERATE Javascript function within Servlet code?

Answer (score 4):

You can't access a Javascript function from your servlet code. Javascript executes on the client (= your user's browser) and the servlet code executes on your server (for example Tomcat, JBoss, whatever you're using).

What are you trying to accomplish with your code? I'm sure there's a simpler way to do it than what you just described.

**[edited]**

I see you just updated your description, so here's my view:

I'm guessing that you want to display a page to the user and when the page is displayed, you want to open a new window which will display another page using the URL parameter to point its address. If this is the case, you should probably just do this in the first page's [onLoad()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) Javascript event using [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: yes. you are right. I need to submit a post request using this method.But window.open triggers GET method by default. So,Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Suki If you actually need to show a page which will automatically submit a form to a popup window, it can be done using Javascript, but I'd say it seems overly complicated. Perhaps if you would tell us what your use case is, then we could better assist you in finding the right solution. I'm finding it hard to believe you would benefit from building it this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `newWindow` property on a `window` object (which is what `parent` references), so this is not unexpected.

Maybe you are looking for the `open` method instead?

If so, then:

- Putting it as the src of an iframe is a very strange thing to do
- It will probably be zapped by pop-up blockers

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You try to generate javascript code inside Servlet code. When you do, your code goes to Web browser and it's seen there as a html document with javascript inside. So, your error rather comes from web browser and links to javascript error. Probably it's newWindow method. To open new window you should call window.open() function, I guess.